# Temporary files disappearing after hours of non-use?

Tags: windows, temporary-files

I maintain a Windows desktop application which stores 12-20 data files under `%TEMP%` within a subfolder when the user creates a new project in the app. (Once the user saves the new project the files are put somewhere else.)

I've had some cases where users have created a new project & left it unsaved for 3-4 hours - also while leaving the app running but not using it. When they eventually go back & try to save they get an error, because **some of the files have disappeared**. But not all of them. There is no obvious pattern to which files are deleted - not by size, internal data, etc.

We have been using this project-file-saving approach for *decades* and this is a new problem (AFAIK). So I wonder if there is some new Windows 10 'feature' or in some other common tool which could be trying to cleanup the TEMP folder aggressively?

This is not a common problem and so far I cannot reproduce it at will, so diagnosis is hard.

We think that the files that get removed *may be* ones with older timestamps. "Older" could be the day before or years before. The pattern is not totally clear yet.

Comment: Since 1709 Windows can automatically clean-up temp files. The automatic clean-up (if activated) via "Storage Sense" should delete after 30 days. May be the system was running low on disk space? Or may be some admin has created a planned task for cleaning up?

Comment: @Robert that is the kind of tip I was looking for... disk space was not an issue but admin settings are a possibility...

Comment: It sounds like some form of automatic maintenance is occurring, through Task Scheduler, group policy, etc.

Comment: Looking at Win10 settings, it may not actually be "Storage Sense" which seems to be specifically about dealing with low disk space, but there is another option in the same spot for "Delete temporary files that my apps aren't using" which might be the culprit.